# Classification on rare events (~%3) and only categorical variables

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, classification, oversampling

I need to build a model based on about 10 independent variables, **all categorical** (only two of which are potentially ordinal), to predict a dichotomous output (**'1'**: 3%; **'0'**: 97%).

To overcome the problem of **class imbalance** I had thought about applying undersampling / oversampling technique ( *undersampling* seems to me the right way given the nature of the predictors, even more so to avoid overfitting).

**In terms of model**, I thought of using a *logistic regression* model as a classifier, because as an output I would also get the expected probabilities (which are still something I need) and the marginal importance of each regressor (in case of a significant relationship).

Being a beginner, in reality, I would not be able to identify which techniques / models / regularizations would fit my scenario well; I'm obviously willing to get my hands dirty as much as possible, but to do this I feel that I should have more arrows to shoot.

In order to do so, I have some doubts:

1. Having only categorical variables and a dichotomous target variable,
   I have the impression that the prediction will not detach itself
   much from the sample frequency of the variables; the idea to improve
   would therefore be to add as much randomness as possible (maybe with a *Random Forest classifier*). Do you
   think it's the correct approach? What could be the side effects?
2. Given the high number of records (> 100K) I do not think a procedure
   for reducing the dimensionality is necessary (I have always
   seen this as a technique for datasets that are too massive in terms of
   variables); however I have seen that in some cases they contribute in
   increasing the precision (or in any case the chosen metric),
   precisely for their ability to eliminate noise. Do you think that in
   such a scenario an MCA
   (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_correspondence_analysis)
   could do for me?
3. More generally, is there any model particularly suitable for such a
   scenario?

Any other advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just replying to issue 2, I would advise against using dimension reduction. Your observation number should allow you to assess the impact of your 10 predictors pretty accurately anyway. The only reason for which dimension reduction could make sense is if some of your predictors are very strongly related to each other, to the extent that your X-matrix filled with dummy variables is singular or very ill-conditioned. Which seems unlikely, and even if it is the case, you could probably resolve it by throwing the guilty predictor out rather than using sophisticated dimension reduction.

Comment: More informally, I don't think as a beginner you get it very wrong using logistic regression, and random forest looks like a good bet as well. Ultimately one cannot say in general what's better; you could use cross-validation to compare them. (You may want to use a loss function that assesses wrong zeroes different from wrong ones, but this depends on subject matter knowledge.)

Comment: In fact, my ultimate goal would be to get the probability, given that set of independent variables, to get the positive outcome (1) as output, and not to label the observations as 0 or 1. In this case, using cross-validation, can I still compare the two models (logistic and RF)? And what logic would follow this comparison? I have the impression of having to go through a 'simple' classification anyway, playing a bit with the thresholds to classify the observations as 0 or 1, or am I wrong?